Vosk Server - Error VoskAPI:Compose():compose-lattice-pruned.cc:889
Estoy usando vosk server para un reconocimiento de voz web, todo funciona bien con el modelo grande en español que ofrece la página de la documentación.
Estoy agregando nuevas palabras al modelo de voz, pero al probar el nuevo compilado en el servidor me muestra la siguiente advertencia:
VoskAPI:Compose():compose-lattice-pruned.cc:889

¿A qué se debe esa advertencia y que podría hacer para darle solución?

¿Esto qué tiene que ver con websockets?. Y, dado que en realidad no hay ningún mensaje sino solo la dirección, si tú escribiste el compose-lattice-pruned.cc y puedes ver qué hay en la línea 899, eso podría orientarte, y si no, parece una pregunta para quién quiera que haya escrito ese archivo. Saludos.
